# ADK or microbridge on ASUS Eee Pad Transformer

Tags: android, usb, arduino, transformer-model, adk

How can the [Android Open Accessory Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html) (ADK) or the microbridge project be made to work with the [ASUS Eee Pad Transformer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASUS_Eee_Pad_Transformer)?

I can compile and install apps on the Transformer which uses that, but when I connect the Transformer to the USB host [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields) nothing happens, it doesn't receive any data from the Transformer. Sometimes the transformer enters in debug mode when connecting to the USB host shield.

---

(Some context, from the first link:

> The main hardware and software components of the ADK include: A USB micro-controller board that is based on the Arduino Mega2560 and Circuits@Home USB Host Shield designs (now referred to as the ADK board), which you will later implement as an Android USB accessory.

)

Answer (score 0):

Right now (July 2011) it appears that the only devices which support the ADK are the Nexus One, Nexus S, and Motorola Xoom.

I note the reference to their current Android ADK Open Challenge which list those devices specifically.

[Open Call for Google Developer Day ADK](https://sites.google.com/site/opencallforgdd/the-challenge)

[Update August 2011]
I've verified that the ADK working with August 2011 update to the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 running 3.1.

Comment: It seems that the only supported devices are these 3.

I have been investigating and microbridge uses the "debugging port" so if a device can make debbuggin in theory you can use microbridge. The eee transformer can do that, you can see the logcat and what you want from eclipse, so microbridge it's suppossed to work. I have tested microbridge in a samsung galaxy s and it works perfect.

I have made some tests with the usb host library and the transformer and my conclusion is that perhaps we have to modify something to add support and it will work, at least the microbridge and probably the adk.

Answer (score 0):

The Eee Pad Transformer works with ADK once it's updated to Android 3.2 I couldn't get it to connect at all using Android 3.1

However, getting the firmware right on the accessory board can be tricky because there are differences between the I/O pins used on various implementations (I've got a Seeeduino ADK board). So if things don't appear to be working it may be your accessory board not the Android device.

Comment: Hi,

I have tried and it works, at least the eee transformer recognizes the accesory and enters into accesory mode. I have to make more test and try to have something functional, but it looks better than before.

Thanks for the information